# Select, categorize, and extract text in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, bookmarks

Goal:
I am doing some qualitative research in Word and am trying to figure out a way to highlight (or otherwise select) passages of text, categorize them, and extract the text and categories to a new document.

Progress/Research:
I found some code at [this site](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/batch-extract-bookmarks-word-document/) that exports bookmarks and bookmarked text to a table (bookmark names in the left column, bookmarked text in the middle, page reference and link in the third). This is almost exactly what I need, except that you can't use the same bookmark name more than once, which is what I'd like to do. I'm getting around this now by appending numbers to my bookmark names (e.g., Context1, Context2, etc.), but is there another method that would just allow me to reuse the same name or label?

P.S. I'm new to the site and only a sporadic user of Stack Exchange, so please excuse and feel free to correct any breaches of etiquette.